# AWS mobile SDK for tvOS

Tags: aws-sdk, tvos

I have developed an iOS project which use AWS mobile SDK ,now I need to port same project for tvOS but as ASW SDK does not support I am stuck with this issue about which analytical library to use. After few search and reading I found this [AWS SDK for tvOS](https://github.com/foldedplane/aws-sdk-tvos/). But I am not sure if all the frameworks would support tvOS. Has anyone tried using ASW SNS services for tvOS? Please do help me if anyone has tried.

Answer (score 0):

[AWS Mobile SDK for iOS does not fully support tvOS](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/issues/317)

### The 5 biggest announcements Apple made at WWDC 2016

> **tvOS is still young but it’s growing up fast.**
>
> The television operating system is expanding its library fast and now
>   has over 1,300 video channels and 6,000 apps.
>
> Siri for tvOS can now easily search for and launch pretty much any
>   kind of media, from movies to YouTube clips.
>
> And apps that you download on your phone will automatically appear on
>   your tvOS.
>
> **The new tvOS will roll out this fall.**

### Resource Link:

https://www.thorntech.com/2016/06/the-5-biggest-announcements-apple-made-at-wwdc-2016/

Comment: Thanks for reply SkyWalker but as we dont know yet how or what kind of support would be provided on tvOS and by what time, we can not wait for it. As tvOS has different frameworks so I could not understand if its only app icon would be shown on tv with iOS tab or will app be able to run on tvOS. I very much doubt about the iOS app running on tvOS. And link which you shared about AWS skd ,I have already questioned there too but could not see any reply.

Comment: @Deep Actually they have not release any stable version. They have just given they will update. But which type of update will come they have not assured. I have also seen some blogs. All people are asking but not luck until now.

Comment: I have used AWS Rest API for TVOS to log all events for analytical calculation. Posting it so it may help others.

Please go through this link [AWS rest API for analytics][1]


  [1]: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobileanalytics/latest/ug/incorporating-mobile-analytics.html

AWS has explained everything in detail,so would suggest to read it before implementing it.

Comment: I was able to successfully integrate the latest SDK of AWS SDK 2.16 but I am seeing issues from 2.18